# Referencing a Swift View Controller from an Objective C View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I can't figure out how to reference  a Swift VC from an Objective C VC in a mixed language project.  Here is Objective C code:

```
#import "NamesVC."

...   ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"peopleSegue"]){
        NamesVC *vc      = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.selEntity     = @"People";
        vc.delegateMethod= @"Admin";
        }
```

**Bridging Header:** Version10-Bridging-Header.h

```
#ifndef Version10_Bridging_Header_h
#define Version10_Bridging_Header_h

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AdminTVC.h"
```

How do you `import` by Swift VC into the Obj C class?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to import any code. I simply want to push the Swift VC from the Obj C VC. For example:                           VC.swift *vc = [[ViC.swift alloc]init];                                                              vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HelpWeb"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; I need to import the VC.swift into the Obj C. The bridging header is used to reference Obj C classes within Swift classes.

Answer (score 2):

Import `ProjectModuleName-swift.h` header inside your `.m` file where you want to access Swift controller like this.

```
#import "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h"
```

After that you are able to access `NamesVC` inside your Objective c `ViewController`.

For more about this read Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) on `Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project`, inside this doc read about **Importing Swift into Objective-C**

Comment: I think in you case you need to import like this `#import "Version10-Swift.h"`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't want to import any code.  I simply want to push the Swift VC from the Obj C VC. For example:                          VC.swift *vc = [[ViC.swift alloc]init];
        vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HelpWeb"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];     I need to import the VC.swift into the Obj C.  The bridging header is used to reference Obj C classes with in Swift classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to import any code", i have told you to import just "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h" in your objective c viewController.m file, Tell me one thing in Objective c if you want to access some other Controller from your ViewController, what you do, obvious you always import that controller to used inside your file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone not finding a solution changing

```
"MyApp-Swift.h"  to   <MyApp-Swift.h>
```

in my objective c .m file that I wanted to reference my swift class

Comment: you are a lifesaver bro. Facing this problem from the past 3 days. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Importing Swift into Objective-C**

> You should  import the Swift code from that target into any Objective-C .m file within that target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate name:

```
#import "NamesVC.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't want to import any code.  I simply want to launch the Swift VC from the Obj C VC. For example: